# ModuleNotFoundError when importing Sequential from Keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I’m encountering an issue when trying to import the Sequential class from Keras. Here’s the code I’m running:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(10000, 64, input_length=80))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Cell In[80], line 1
----> 1 model=Sequential()
      2 model.add(Embedding(10000,64,input_length=80))
      3 model.add(LSTM(100))

File c:\Users\Isaac\anaconda3\envs\textattackenv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:184, in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\Isaac\anaconda3\envs\textattackenv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\version_utils.py:61, in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\Isaac\anaconda3\envs\textattackenv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py:1221, in __getattr__(self, item)

File c:\Users\Isaac\anaconda3\envs\textattackenv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py:1212, in _load(self)

File c:\Users\Isaac\anaconda3\envs\textattackenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127, in import_module(name, package)
    125             break
    126         level += 1
--> 127 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1014, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:991, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:973, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine.base_layer_v1'
```

I’m not sure why this is happening. I’ve tried reinstalling Keras and TensorFlow, but the issue persists. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base\_layer\_v1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509657/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-python-keras-engine-base-layer)

Comment: no it doesnt help , but finally i managed to use a very specific version compatibible with my other function and 'from keras.models import Sequential'